# Custom Maven Archetype bad xml formatting with Java 11

Tags: java, maven, maven-archetype

I'm facing a problem with custom Maven archetypes using Java 11. 
I defined a custom archetype and when I run the `mvn archetype:generate` the tool generates a correct application but with a formatting glitch in the file pom.xml.

This is a snipped from the original pom.xml file packed inside the archetype:

```
    <groupId>$thegroupId</groupId>
    <artifactId>$theArtifactId</artifactId>
    <version>$theVersion</version>
    <description>Archetype standard</description>
```

This is the pom.xml of the generated Java application

```
 <groupId>com.aruba.test</groupId>
            
  
  
  
  <artifactId>test-no-db</artifactId>
            
  
  
  
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
            
  
  
  
  <description>Archetype standard</description>
```

Other files (.java and others xml files) are formatted without any glitch. The only trouble is related with the pom.xml file.

I did several tests and the only solution is to downgrade to java 8. Using this JDK version, the pom.xml is formatted as expected.

Is this situation familiar for any?

Thanks

Comment: Please show the whole archetype setup...

Comment: I found out that this is an unresolved bug with the maven-archetype-plugin

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARCHETYPE-587
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARCHETYPE-584

Comment: Have you use the most recent version of archetype-plugin?

Comment: yes I'm using the latest version. If I downgrade to the version 3.10, the problem disappears, but this version has a problem with dom4j that has been fixed in the recent ones.
I applied a 'dirty fix' for the moment. I developed a groovy post generation script that cleans the empty lines. I'm not happy at all with this solution but at least it does its job